# When I call setResultClass(...) in JDO/DataNucleus for an aggregate function JDOUserException is thrown

Tags: java, jdo, datanucleus

With the following code

```
    Query query = pm.newQuery(User.class);
    query.setFilter( "username == :usernameParam" );
    query.setResult( "count(username)" );
    query.setResultClass(Long.class);
    Object result = query.execute(username);
    return (result!=null && (Long)result>0);
```

I get this exception:

> javax.jdo.JDOUserException: The Query
>   will return a single field but it is
>   not of a consistent type as the
>   ResultClass (java.lang.Long) : It is
>   java.lang.Long

If I remove the `.setResult(Long.class)` query it works and I get back a Long.

Perhaps I don't understand the `setResult()` method. I had understood that I need to set this to indicate what type of result I wanted. But is this not the case with aggregate functions such as `count()`?

Comment: With the setResultClass(Long.class) shouldn't your next line of code be allowed to be Long result = (Long)query.execute(username)?

Comment: Ah yes, of course. And it was, in my first go-around, I failed to revert back to the "expected" version for posting (lots of manipulations during debugging), but the problem is all the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That was fixed several days ago. Fortunately for you versions 2.1.3 and 2.2 M3 were released an hour or so ago ;-)

Comment: Wow, now there's some kind of service for you, report a problem and get an, "it was fixed an hour ago," response!  So anyway, you're saying my code is correct and I should just upgrade right? Um, just curious (since it's what I tried first), if I setResult(Integer.class), would that also be considered correct?

Comment: "count" returns Long as per the spec. And no you don't have to set the resultClass, as per the spec also